# Trouble with redefining operator+ (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, redefine

```
class Community
{
private:
    char* Name;
    char foundationDate[11];
    Person founderPtr;
    int maxMembersCount;
    int membersCount;
    Person* members;
    static int communitiesCount;
public:

.
.
.
Person* operator+(Community&); // operator + prototype (must return array of members)
};

Person* Community::operator+(Community& other)
{
Community temp("temp","12.11.1993",other.getFounder());
Person* ptr;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < this->getMembersCount() ; i++)
{
        for(int j = 0 ; j < other.getMembersCount() ; j++)
    {

        if(strcmp(this->members[i].getEGN(),other.members[j].getEGN()) == 0)
        {
            temp.addMember(other.members[j]);
        }
    }
}
ptr = temp.getMembers();
return ptr;
}
```

If I `cout<< ptr[i];` in the function I can seen everything is ok, but when I try :

```
 Community S("obshnost","12.11.2010",A);
Community R("community","11.10.2011",B);
S.addMember(C);
S.addMember(Z);
R.addMember(C);


Person* ptr = S+R;
 for(int i = 0 ; i<2 ; i ++)
{
cout<<ptr[i];
 }
```

I see messed up results ... If someone have an idea what I should look for i'll be thankful :)

Comment: This whole thing makes no sense at all. Please show some code where the desired op+ would be used for some good.

Comment: looks like you computing the list of common members. Btw, you can just `return temp.getMembers()`, no need for the confusing variable `ptr`.

Comment: Would agree your post is confusing. However I think you are struggling partly because you're avoiding the use of standard data structures. Try using std::vector or QList or something similar to hold your list of members.

Answer (score 0):

I cant't say say for sure without seeing the rest of your source code, but I would guess your + operator is returning a pointer to memory that has already been released.